# Slope change after a lag in interrupted time series analysis

Tags: time-series, regression, poisson

I am using the 'its2es' package in R for an interrupted time series analysis, and I suspect the slope change might occur after a lag since the intervention. How can we define the impact model to include this slope change after a lag?

This hypothesis is based on contextual information, and currently the slope and the level change are not significant.